# Swift: Cannot convert value of type '() -> Bool' to expected argument type 'PFObject'

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

In the overall scheme of things I am trying to compare the user's multiple selections from a tableview and compare them to my Parse database. So my problem is twofold 1. Is my current code going about it the correct way? and 2. How can I convert value type Bool to argument type PFObject?

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> Bool' to expected argument type 'PFObject'

[image]

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if segue.identifier == "showResults" {

        // Get reference to destination view controller
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! CollectionViewController

        if let selectedItem = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows{

            for var i = 0; i < selectedItem.count; ++i {

                var currentPath = selectedItem[i] as NSIndexPath
                var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(currentPath)

                if let cell = cell {

                    //add major(s) selected to data variable in collectionview as type text(String)
                    destination.data.append(cell.textLabel!.text!)

                }
```

let imagesQuery = PFQuery(className:"CollegeImages")
                    imagesQuery.selectKeys(["name"])
                    imagesQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let returnedobjects = objects {
                                //objects array isn't nil
                                //loop through the array to get each object
                                for object in returnedobjects {
                                    print(object["name"] as! String)
                                }
                            }

```
                    }
                })

                let majorSelected:String = (cell?.textLabel!.text!)!
                let query = PFQuery(className:"CollegeMajors")
                query.selectKeys(["Major"])
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in

                    if error == nil {
                        // The find succeeded.
                        print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) majors.", terminator: "")
                        // Do something with the found objects
                        if let returnedobjects = objects {
                            if returnedobjects.contains ({($0["Major"] as? String)! == majorSelected}) && query.selectKeys(["College Name"]) ==  imagesQuery.selectKeys(["name"]) {
                                print("your in!") // transition to the new screen

                            }
                            else {
                                print("your out.") // do whatever
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Log details of the failure
                        print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)", terminator: "")
                    }
                })
            }

        }


    }






}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //Keep track of which major(s) the user selected
    let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath){


        //Trigger the segue to go to the collection view
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showResults", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: drop the `(` and `)` around the `{ ... }`

Comment: Please add the source code and error messages as text. Images are not searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Your line of interest holds several problems.

First of all, you are passing a closure `{["returnedobjects"] as? String == path }` to `contains(_:)` method, but the closure does not take any arguments. You need to pass a closure taking one argument, where its type being the same as the element of the array.

Second, inside the closure, `["returnedobjects"]` is an array, so, `["returnedobjects"] as? String` always fails and generates `nil`. You need to change this part to a meaningful expression producing `String`, you may need to utilise the `PFObject` instances passed to this closure.

Third, you declare `path` as:

```
let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

which means the local variable has type `NSIndexPath`. So, even if the left hand side of `==` returns a valid `String`, you cannot compare `String` to `NSIndexPath`. You may need to get a `String` value before comparing.

---

With considering all three above and with some guess, you need to:

Add one line below `let path = ...`

```
let majorSelected: String = (Some expression to retrieve "major" from the `path`)
```

Change the closure in the line containing `contains` as:

```
if returnedobjects.contains ({$0["Major"] as? String == majorSelected }) {
```

Comment: Thanks @OOPer this seems to work, however I am getting an error when applying the && logic operator in my if statement after the "}" stating "no && candidates produce the expected contextual result type".  I am inserting this && operator because I need to compare one collection in my Parse database with another collection to then display the results of the user's selection. Any thoughts on the error?

Comment: If your 'after the "}"' means something like `if returnedobjects.contains ({$0["Major"] as? String == majorSelected } && (...) ) {`, then you are misplacing your `&&`. It needs to be something like this: `if returnedobjects.contains ({$0["Major"] as? String == majorSelected }) && (...) {`. And if you feel it's difficult to explain your issue in a comment, please edit your post and append your latest code.

Comment: I edited my post, why would I be getting an error saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" which doesn't make sense because every row in each of my Parse database collection's tables has a value and the only time I've gotten this error in the past is when a table value is empty which isn't the case.

Comment: You are using some forced unwrapping `!`, so you have much chance to get that "unexpectedly found nil". Where exactly that error is happening?

Comment: Its strange when I insert a breakpoint I can't tell where the error is occurring, but when I run the code as normal without inserting a break point I get an error as soon as I make a selection in my tableview.

Comment: The most doubtful part in your edited code is this: `{($0["Major"] as? String)! == majorSelected}`. I don't know why you needed `!` here. And are you 100% sure, $0["Major"] can never be nil?

Comment: I think I know why I might be getting nil...I believe my database collections are misaligned meaning one collection has more info than the other so I get nil when the results are returned. I need to merge the collections probably with 1 to many relationship.

Comment: would you have any idea as to why when I run a PFQuery on one collection it runs fine but I run it on a different collection with nearly the same information it returns nil and the app crashes?

Comment: @AlexCowley , as you have experienced, a slight mistake may lead fatal errors. So, I cannot figure out what's happening with a short comment. Create a minimized code which can reproduce your issue, and post it as another question, that's my best recommendation.